# jQuery AJAX synchronous but "pauses" tab till finished

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, synchronization, synchronous

I'm trying to send a few AJAX requests. It has to collect the data into a variable, and after it's done, it has to output the variable. If I don't do it synchronously, it will just output the variable before the requests are done. Is is possible to keep using the page, while the requests are running? The code could look something like this:

```
for (var i=0;i<10;i++) {
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "http://google.com",
        async: false,
        data: "",
        success:function(data){
            total += $(data);
            alert(total);
    }
}
```

That should load http://google.com/ 10 times, and output data into a variable called total. It is not my code I use (I like to keep it as private as possible), but only an example.

While it's loading Google 10 times, the page pauses because of **async: false**. Is is possible to make the page still work, and basically do the AJAX in the background? While it's loading, I can't do anything on the page.

Comment: `async: false,`  please, NO!

Comment: Set async to true, then use callbacks or deferred objects so that you only "output the variable" after the call has completed. Welcome to the world of async.

Comment: Yes, set `async: true` and write your code to work asynchronously.

Comment: Do this and do that. Give me some examples, please. I come here for help. Setting it to true crashed my tab, so that won't work.

Comment: that's likely because you're trying to use `total` before all of the ajax requests are complete. We need to see more of your code.

Comment: please do some research before asking other to code it for you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-to-return-the-response-from-an-ajax-call  Then, if you are stuck somewhere, ask a new question

Comment: Flagged as off-topic, because to ask how to make an AJAX call work in the background (asynchronously) is the same as to ask how to make the mother a relative of yours.

Comment: Exactly. How do I fix that? Some help would be appreciated.

Comment: It depends on what the end goal of your code is. with what you have provided we can't figure that out.

Comment: I want to load $(data) into the variable total. 10 times, as my code indicates.

Comment: Right. but what are you doing with it after.

Comment: Displaying it on a page..? Why does this matter to the code? :)

Comment: It matters because you can't simply return that variable from a function, or access it after the for loop. You can only do anything with it after all of the ajax requests have completed.

Comment: Exactly, that's what I am trying to do. Doesn't look like Stackoverflow is much help on this topic. I think I'll delete it.

Comment: There is something else that you can return from the function that gives you access to the value though.

Comment: @LemvigKiggeren seriously, all is explain here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-to-return-the-response-from-an-ajax-call   So where are you stuck? If you want other to code for you, hire someone...

Answer (score 0):

> If I don't do it synchronously, it will just output the variable before the requests are done.

No, it will output the variable 10 times after *each* request is done. To avoid that, use counter for how many requests have finished:

```
for (var i=0;i<10;i++) {
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "http://google.com",
        async: true,
        data: "",
        success:function(data){
            total += $(data);
            if (!--i)
                alert(total);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You still have `async: true` in your snippet tho

Comment: @DavidHedlund what do you mean?

Comment: Bah, what do I mean indeed. I thought `false` in my head, as I expected the property to not be specified at all. Disregard me.